# Swift Sprite Kit Physics Body: Ball slows down after applying an impulse

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I am quite new to Swift and the Sprite Kit!

I tried to build a Pong game. Everything works well but the ball on which I am applying an impulse **slows down** really quickly!
I already turned off **gravity**, **friction** and damping and set the **restitution** of the ball and the scene to 1.

Here is my Code:

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    
  let player = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: 200, height: 30))
  let enemy = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: 200, height: 30))
  let ball = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 10)

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

let border = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
    border.restitution = 1
    border.friction = 0
    border.angularDamping = 0
    border.linearDamping = 0

    self.physicsBody = border

    scene?.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)

    player.position = CGPoint(x:  0, y: -(scene?.size.height)! * 0.35)
    player.fillColor = UIColor.white
    player.strokeColor = UIColor.clear
    self.addChild(player)

    player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: 200, height: 30))
    player.physicsBody?.friction = 0
    player.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    player.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0
    player.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
    player.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
    player.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false

    enemy.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: (scene?.size.height)! * 0.35)
    enemy.fillColor = UIColor.white
    enemy.strokeColor = UIColor.clear
    self.addChild(enemy)

    enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: 200, height: 30))
    enemy.physicsBody?.friction = 0
    enemy.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    enemy.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
    enemy.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0
    enemy.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false

    ball.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    ball.fillColor = UIColor.white
    ball.strokeColor = UIColor.clear

    ball.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0
    ball.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
    ball.physicsBody?.friction = 0
    ball.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
    ball.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    ball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 10)
    ball.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    self.addChild(ball)
    ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: -30, dy: -30))



  }

   override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {

        let pos = touch.location(in: self)

        player.position.x = pos.x

     }
  }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
         if ball.position.y >  0{
         enemy.position.x = ball.position.x
         }
    }
 }
```

Thank you already!

Comment: You didn't set the `linearDamping` for the ball. Also, you'll need to add the ball to the scene before applying an impulse.

Comment: Thank you. It helped a bit because it is moving faster now but the ball is still slowing down...

Comment: You create the physicsbody way too late

Comment: What do you mean with that? Should I bring all the code for the ball to the top? Or should I create a function for setting it up and then call this function at the begging of the code?

Comment: You are setting properties for the physicsbody before you even create it,  look at how you create it for every other node, and make sure your ball does it the exact same way

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Now it is working perfectly! How can I mark this question to be answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to always create your physics body before you change its properties

```
ball.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0
ball.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
ball.physicsBody?.friction = 0
ball.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
ball.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
ball.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 10) <----Needs to be first
ball.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
self.addChild(ball)
ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: -30, dy: -30))
```